# Why Xcode don't prompt a crash reason?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this issue for a long time.
The Xcode DO NOT prompt more information about the compiling error.

If I create a new project, the Xcode could show the error reason.

[image: normal]

But in another project, it DO NOT show any detail information about the error.

[image: error]

I have no idea to resolve the issue.

---

OS X: 10.11.5
Xcode: 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

some well known Exception can be easily catched by Xcode and shown with the right error description.
What you can do is to add a AllException break point to make your code break onThrow then inspect/debug your code [image] [image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using the exception break point to locate the error code. This is a good way to resolve the issue. But I am inquisitive about this issue, why does Xcode do not show a detail info.

Comment: As shown from crash its related to something not supported in similatior but its needs device... Like trying to use camera or other feature avaible only in device

Comment: ..also in your case exception happen in your JPush sdk ... That may not have access to code but on'y compilled version